# Link CiviCase with CiviAccounts

Tags: civicase, financial-accounts

I was wondering how would you configure CiviCase to link with CiviAccounts.

So for instance: you set up a new case to process a member's expense for train tickets. Can you link that from the case management to the accounts? So that you can keep a log of their interactions and processes, including finances.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail? I do not understand the question. The case IS a log of  their interactions? Or do you want to create a financial transaction for the expense?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'd normally add various activity types to that case. I.e. create an activity type Expenses Claim and add that.

Comment: Agree with the Activity Type approach. Case might be overkill

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar to this with Activity types. When a person needs to be reimbursed they submit an Activity type called "Check Request" and assign it to the person that needs to approve it. That person will review it and set the status to Approved and then assign it to the next person to approve. We have detailed logging enabled and each time the activity is approved/denied/assigned a log event is recorded. We had Jon write us an extension that would show the log history for the Activity type at the bottom of the Activity. That way the person who cuts the check could see that all the approvals necessary were given.

I'd like to make some improvements to it so that the Statuses would be "Approve and Route", "Deny and Return", etc. And use Relationships to automatically assign the activity based on who is the supervisor of the person approving it. But that's down the road.

It's got several hard coded items in the code like the activity type id, and specific activity status id's but the code is at
https://github.com/PalanteJon/org.saintfranciscocc.checkflow